# How to create iOS simple text animation?

Tags: ios, animation, xcode4.5

What is the best solution for simple iOS text/label animation? The details: user need to see one label on the iOS screen with changed text from array de 10-15 words, one word by step separated by white screen.The  show time the  one word is 800-900 ms and the show time the white screen  is 500 ms. There is one kind of the attention test.

Comment: I have done it before by using NSTimer only. And it works pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to flash words, you can use `NSTimer` or just [`performSelector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a):

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *words;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger wordIndex;

@end

@implementation ViewController

static CGFloat const kWordShowInterval = 0.8;
static CGFloat const kWordHideInterval = 0.4;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.words = @[@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four"];
    self.wordIndex = 0;

    [self showWord];
}

- (void)showWord
{
    if (self.wordIndex >= [self.words count])
        return;

    self.wordLabel.text = self.words[self.wordIndex];

    [self performSelector:@selector(hideWord)
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:kWordShowInterval];
}

- (void)hideWord
{
    self.wordLabel.text = nil;

    self.wordIndex++;
    if (self.wordIndex < [self.words count])
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(showWord)
                   withObject:nil
                   afterDelay:kWordHideInterval];
    }
    else
    {
        // all done, go ahead and invoke whatever you want to do when done presenting the words
    }
}

@end
```

If you wanted to do some animation of the appearance or disappearance of the text (e.g. fade it in or out), you could combine this with an [`animateWithDuration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111) or other animation construct.

Comment: Awesome!  Note that if you want this animation to continue updating even when other UI elements are going (UIScrolLView, for example), you need to schedule the recurring process with NSRunLoopCommonModes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Core Animation is the best way. Check out [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I think not. If he really wanted to animate the transition as the label goes from text to blank or back [`animateWithDuration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW109) would be far easier. But I think that's not the question, here.

Comment: OK, what is can be event/dispatcher for begin the show by (for NNString word : arrayWords) when new page will be show?Without the user interaction..Thanks